# is there a way to display a diagonally hatched material for a Cesium polygon

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to create a special material for a Cesium Polygon, which has to incorporate a hatched area with an outline.
Now, from the base materials I can use "Stripe", so i can create my graphic like this:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var degrees_array = [
    92.1470732697006,
    21.954465553476467,
    99.08781126987297,
    32.557089696031916,
    68.66765785924682, 
    24.272023818381587
];
var polygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'polygon',
    polygon : {
    hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(degrees_array),
    extrudedHeight: 0,
    material : new Cesium.StripeMaterialProperty(
                {
                    evenColor:Cesium.Color.GRAY,
                    oddColor:Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                    orientation: Cesium.StripeOrientation.HORIZONTAL,
                    repeat:100,
                    offset:0

                }
    ),
            //outline is ignored by WebGL 
            //outline: true,
            //outlineColor:Cesium.Color.BLACK,
            //outlineWidth:1
    }
});
//since designing an outline is not possible with polygon we create a custom polylineGraphics:
var outline_array = degrees_array;
// since loop is not available for polylineGraphics we add the first point positions
outline_array.push(outline_array[0],outline_array[1]);
var outline = viewer.entities.add({
   polyline : {
    positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(outline_array),
    width : 5,
    material : Cesium.Color.GRAY,
    clampToGround:true,
    zIndex:0
   }
});

viewer.zoomTo(polygon)
```

see [sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

My questions: 
- is there a way to rotate the stripes, so that they appear as diagonally hatched
- can zoom be omitted for the Stripe material, so that it is always displayed with the same line width?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still wondering. You can rotate the stripes by using stRotation

```
  polygon: {
    hierarchy: <posititons>
    stRotation: Cesium.Math.toRadians(45),
    material: stripeMaterial,
  }
```

Comment: I was indeed still wondering :) 
Much appreciated!